# std::function template param can not be deduced

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, std-function, template-argument-deduction

I'm working on code like following one

```
#include <functional>

template <typename Type>
void foo(const std::function<void(const Type&)> & handler) {}

void goo (const int&){}

int main() {
    foo([](const int&){});
    foo(goo);
}
```

unfortunate it refuses to compile on (clang 6.0.0 and gcc 8.1.1) due to following error

```
candidate template ignored: could not match 'function<void (const type-parameter-0-0 &)>' against '(lambda at test3.cpp:13:9)'
candidate template ignored: could not match 'function<void (const type-parameter-0-0 &)>' against '(lambda at test3.cpp:13:9)'
```

Is it possible to somehow force it to deduce `Type` correctly?

Comment: Do you *have* to use `std::function` for the argument? If you look at just about *all* standard library functions taking a callable argument (like many of the [algorithm functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm)) they use a single template argument for the callable type, which in you case could be something like `template<typename C> void foo(C handler) { ... }`

Comment: After that im storing those action in list for each Type to be called later.

Comment: @majkrzak You can force the construction of `std::function` object. `foo(std::function<void(const int&)>(&goo));`

Comment: `foo<int>` is more reasonable in that case

Comment: Is anything keeping you from adding the template parameter to the call? It compiles for me, then: `foo<int>([](const int&){});`

Comment: If you store the function to be used later, how do you know what argument to use when calling it? You have to remember that templates is a *compile-time only* thing, and storing a function object to call later is something that happens at run-time, when there is no imformation about types or templates available. Perhaps if you ask about the *actual* problem you want to solve with a solution to this, we might be able to help you with that instead? Please take some time to read about [the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @GeckoGeorge point that I want to get rid of it

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Actual problem is to create event dispatcher. Current version works now fine, but I'm trying to add there some sugar. Also, I wan't to enclose it in class.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude most generic problem may be "How to store Callable in generic way".

Comment: https://gist.github.com/majkrzak/043947c17cb475cd630e8a633f4d9d71

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You tagged C++17, so you can use deduction guides for `std::function`'s.

You can try something as follows

```
template <typename F,
          typename Type = typename decltype(std::function{std::declval<F>()})::argument_type>
void foo (F f)
 {
 }
```

I know that `argument_type` is deprecated in C++17, but you can substitute it with a simple custom template.

By example

```
template <typename>
struct firstArg;

template <typename R, typename A0, typename ... As>
struct firstArg<std::function<R(A0, As...)>>
 { using type = A0; };
```

and `foo()` can be written as

```
template <typename F,
          typename FUNC = decltype(std::function{std::declval<F>()}),
          typename Type = typename firstArg<FUNC>::type>
void foo (F f)
 {
 }
```

This way the callable `f` isn't a `std::function` but it's original type (and this can be better or worse, depending from your exact requirements); if you need it in a `std::function`, you can obtain it inside the `foo()` function using again deduction guides or the `FUNC` type

```
template <typename F,
          typename FUNC = decltype(std::function{std::declval<F>()}),
          typename Type = typename firstArg<FUNC>::type>
void foo (F f)
 {
   FUNC fnc{f};
 }
```

Comment: Thx, It seems to be what I needed

Comment: @majkrzak - answer improved a little